# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.setResolvedFactoryMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have upgraded spring all libraries from 5.1.8.RELEASE to 5.2.12.RELEASE. On running spring application getting the following issue. The method is called but the method does not exist in spring. This was working fine in spring 5.1.8.RELEASE. As a part of spring kafka upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.4.1. Getting the following error.

```
Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition

16:23:07.204 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$ConfigurationClassBeanDefinition.setResolvedFactoryMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:234) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar:2.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.2.12.RELEASE.jar:2.2.12.RELEASE]
```

My pom.xml is

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.noggit/noggit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.noggit</groupId>
            <artifactId>noggit</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- kafka dependency -->

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```

Please help here.

Comment: Please add your full `pom.xml`. Explain how you are deploying this and finally run `mvn dependency:tree` to see which dependencies you actually pull in. The fact that you state you managed dependencies to a certain versions makes me wonder what manual management you do (and still trying to outsmart the spring boot starters).

Comment: I believe that SpringFox brings you incompatible with that Spring Boot dependencies. Consider to find the right one or exclude Spring from Fox letting Spring Boot to manage it